# How to define a schema full mode for a class in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am a new learner on OrientDB and have this question about schema. How to define a **schema-full** mode for a new class -say person class? Similarly how to define the schema-hybrid mode -using sql?

Somehow I can't make out this from the documentation.

Thanks,
DBuserN

Answer (score 2):

The schema-full mode is controlled on a per-class basis and can be enabled or disabled using the STRICTMODE keyword.  For example:

alter class Person strictmode=true;

For reference
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Alter-Class.html

Answer (score 1):

- **Schema-full** Enables strict-mode at a class-level and sets all fields as mandatory.
- **Schema-less** Enables classes with no properties. Default is non-strict-mode, meaning that records can have arbitrary fields.
- **Schema-hybrid** Enables classes with some fields, but allows records to define custom fields. This is also sometimes called schema-mixed.

You can define schema, as you create the structure of your DB. So if you define properties on a class it will be schema-full. A class without properties and it will be schema-less etc...

You can fine more information on [official documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Schema.html).

Hope it helps.